# Diferença entre receber armazenar um base64 em propriedade do tipo byte[] vs string

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, http-request

bom basicamente a minha dúvida é sobre boas práticas quando manipular um base64 e se tem algum ganho de performance ao tentar armazenar o base64 em uma propriedade do tipo **string** ou um **byte[]**

Coloquei um exemplo de cenário abaixo para ficar um pouco mais fácil:

Digamos que você tem essa classe abaixo que representa uma input model

```
public sealed class DocumentoPessoaInputModel{
    public string TipoDocumento {get; set;}
    public byte[] ImagemDocumentoBase64 {get; set;}
}
```

E você tem o seguinte método dentro de um Controller qualquer

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadDeDocumentoAsync([FromBody] DocumentoPessoaInputModel inputModel){
    //Fazer o upload da imagem
    return Ok()
}
```

A minha dúvida em si é no **DocumentoPessoaInputModel** a propriedade **ImagemDocumentoBase64**, como ela é um base64 e a propriedade é um array de bytes, existiria algum ganho eu trocar para uma string ao invés de um byte[]? Lembrando que nesse cenário estarei trabalhando somente com um base64.

Em alguns tutoriais, vejo que é utilizado uma propriedade do tipo string para armazenar um base64.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro é importante entender o que é um [base64](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), nada mais é do que a representação em ASCII de um conjunto de bytes, por si só a representação em base64já faz ser 33% maior que a representação original binária.

Então a forma correta e clara de armazenar um base64 é usando o tipo **string**, caso precise salvar esta representação em qualquer lugar, vale converter para bytes usando o método apropriado, uma vez que diminuirá o tamanho final, pelo que foi citado no primeiro parágrafo, para a conversão simplesmente use:

```
Convert.FromBase64String(suaStringBase64)
```